# How to use @produces annotation?

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, annotations, jersey

I want to use @Produces({Mediatype.Application_XML , Mediatype.Application_JSON}) in a program that I am writing. I want to use this on only one method, but I am confused that when will it return a JSON object and when will it return an XML page. Here is the code I am writing and in both the cases it returns me an XML feed. I want it to return an JSON object if it does not meet the if-else criterion.

```
@Path("/{search}")
@GET
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML}) 
public String getCountryData(@PathParam("search") String search,    @QueryParam("ccode") String ccode , @QueryParam("scode") String scode) {

    if(ccode.equals("XML")){
        return "<note> <to>Tove</to> <from>Jani</from><heading>Reminder</heading> <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body></note>";   
    }   

    return EndecaConn.ConnectDB("Search", search,"mode matchallpartial" );
}
```

Comment: When a client HTTP `Accept` header is for XML (`text/xml`), it will return XML. If it's `application/json`, it will return json.

Comment: I dont know what the client is going to use..and I cant change the accept header of the client...because I am not the client..is there no other way to do it..except for creating two new methods

Comment: That depends on your client.

Comment: There's not much point in using `@Produces` if you're going to write the xml or json yourself.

Comment: It'a all about content negotiation. Google this term to get to know the mechanism better

Answer (score 1):

The media type will be part of the request, you shouldn't include it as a query parameter.  Below is some sample Java code that would request the data as `application/xml`.

```
String uri =
    "http://localhost:8080/CustomerService/rest/customers/1";
URL url = new URL(uri);
HttpURLConnection connection =
    (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/xml");

JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);
InputStream xml = connection.getInputStream();
Customer customer =
    (Customer) jc.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(xml);

connection.disconnect();
```

---

In your example you could have different methods corresponding to the same path for the different media types.

```
@Path("/{search}")
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) 
public String getCountryDataJSON(@PathParam("search") String search, @QueryParam("scode") String scode) {
    return JSON;
}

@Path("/{search}")
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML) 
public String getCountryDataXML(@PathParam("search") String search, @QueryParam("scode") String scode) {
    return XML;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to return a Response object with the entity set to your domain entity. The serialization of the xml/json is done automatically.

See: https://jsr311.java.net/nonav/releases/1.1/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html

yYou can return an entity like this:

```
Foo myReturn = new Foo(blah,blah,blah)
return Response.ok(myReturn).build()
```

If you need fine grained serialization you can use annotations on your domain class.

Comment: return EndecaConn.ConnectDB("Search", search,"mode matchallpartial" ) does serialization to JSON for me. I have used an object mapper that converts Java objects to JSON objects. So my class EndecaConn takes care of that. I think that is what you meant.

Comment: You can do either. Returning a Response object allows you to also set specific headers, a URI and a response code along with your entity.